# Better Indexes for the queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have 2 tables:

**oders** `(order_id, customer_id, order_date, product_id, order_quantity)`

**customers**`(customer_id, last_name, first_name, favorite_website )`

Also I have an application that makes frequent questions in the tables using the following commands:

```
  SELECT * FROM orders where customer_id = @id

    SELECT * FROM orders where customer_id = @id and order_date > @date

    SELECT * FROM orders where order_date > @date1 and order_date < @date2

    SELECT first_name, last_name, favorite_website FROM customers where last_name = @last_name

    SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name,favorite_website
FROM customers where last_name = @last_name and favorite_website = @site
```

I want to find some indexes on these tables that their creation would accelerate the implementation of the above questions.

The only indexes I found are:

```
1.`create index indexorders on orders (order_id, customer_id, order_date, product_id, order_quantity);` 

2.`create index indexcust on customers (customer_id, last_name, first_name, favorite_website );`
```

Are any other indexes that are better than these? Can you suggest some?

Comment: Do you really want `*` in `select` for all the queries ? Because Index can be optimised based ion column selection as well

Comment: Putting the order_id column first in any index is useless since your example workload never searches on it. Since you have BETWEEN and > and < against `order_date`, it might make sense to make `order_date` the first column of your clustered index, and perhaps `customer_id` as the second column of your clustered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On orders table..

create primary key(`customerid,orderdate`) (if unique) on orders table or  use below combination.**This index will work for only the combinations of queries provided in the question**

```
create index nci_custid_ordt on dbo.orders
(
customerid,
orderdate)
include
(
order_id, product_id, order_quantity)
```

For Customers table

create a non clustered index using below combination

```
create index nci_lstname_fw on dbo.customers
(
last_name,favorite_website)
include
(customer_id, first_name)
```

You can create customerid as primary key and orderid as primary key in their respective tables,but i don't see any benefit ,if you don't use them in your queries..

Comment: I suggest the columns be orderdate, customerid, since there are two range queries on orderdate

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:that will leave a residual on customerid,the index i suggested won't

Comment: hmmmm I think maybe I'm out of my depth here but why would a residual be required if it's a covering index? columns in either order satisfy two out of the first three queries, except that the leading orderdate lends itself to range queries.

Comment: residual can occur ,even if the index is covering.Refer to below link for more details  :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/07/seek-predicates/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. "we can only use the index to satisfy a predicate on the second column if we have an equality predicate on the first column" explains it for me. It's good to learn new things :)